# From where do I import settings from previous version of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, settings, settings.bundle

I was running Droidio (Android Studio) 0.6.1; from there I was not able to update to the newest version (a quantum leap to 0.8); I had to download it separately and install from Windows Explorer. But now the installation process is looking for old settings:

[image]

Where it seems to want to take me is here (to the Android folder, I reckon); this is what I see when I mash the "compressed ellipsis" (one dot) button:

[image]

...but I'm not sure that is really the right spot; Is it [not]? What is the precise name of the settings file I should be seeking?

### UPDATE

I followed Gabriele's directive, and then I got this:

[image]

I chose "Use Android Studio's SDK"

And then I got this when trying to rebuild my project, "*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preBuild'. failed to find target android-19 : C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk*"

### UPDATE 2

I then opened the SDK Manager and installed what was missing/out of date, and tried to build again.

I got the error, "*Failed to refresh Gradle project 'Platypus' Error: Cause: failed to find target android-19: C:\users\clay\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk Install missing platform and sync project*

The "*Install missing platform and sync project*" part of the message is a link. I clicked it, accepted the License Agreement.

Once that finished, the build failed again with a similar message: "*...failed to find Build Tools revision 19.1.0 Install Build Tools 19.1.0 and sync project*"

Again, the "*install...*" jazz was a link; I clicked it, accepted, and installed...

The next problem child was, "*Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.11.2) Fix plug-in version and re-import project*"

Acquiescing to the counsel of the wise old man in "*Never Cry Wolf*," I endeavored to persevere by clicking "Fix plug-in version and re-import project"

At which point I finally got a successful build.

### UPDATE 3

I then ran the project, and it seemed to be running (it said so, and the red square was visible), but no emulator ever appeared.

I opened the AVD Manager, and the device had a warning icon (repairable). I clicked the "Repair" button; it seemed to work - the warning icon disappeared.

But then I got this:

[image]

It still won't display an emulator when I Run > Debug App...

It used to be (with Droidio 0.5* to 0.61) that the first time I ran, I would see this:

[image]

...and the Emulator would eventually come up; subsequent runs of the app, the Device would be listed at the top (under "Choose a Running Device") - no more, though - it is only at the bottom as shown in the scream shot above, even on subsequent runs of the app...

I reckon I should try "re-creating the AVD's weird, malformed config.ini" but don't savvy just what steps to take to accomplish that.

Comment: Likewise when I try to, I guess the old settings are not compatible with the BETA version.

Comment: If I accidentally chose the don't import option when this dialog popped up, is there a place inside Android Studio that I can import my old settings later?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I used a method to trick the Android Studio to import settings from previous one without exporting the settings and it worked.

Just go to your previous `.AndroidStudio\config` folder, copy and paste them all to the new one (in my scenario I updated from 1.1 to 1.2 beta) `.AndroidStudioPreview1.2`

(For preventing any failure, please make a Rar file of your original config, 
also, after it works, export it so you can import it if you need it)

Comment: Is there a specific way to do this? I copied all the files from \config of 1.1 to the .AndroidStudioPreview1.2 but after opening Android Studio, my settings were all default, after checking the config folder, all the settings had reverted.  Is there any way to make it stick?

Comment: Interesting, It didn't happened to me, but let me know about: 1- did you copy the whole folder and replace it to the new one? 2- Did you try this when your Android Studio was closed?

Comment: I copied the whole \config folder yes. Android Studio was closed at the time. I also tried adding the files, then exporting my settings to a settings.jar, but when I import it, and restart Android Studio, it reverts back to the default again. It's very odd, and infuriating.

Comment: OK a restart fixed it somehow. The magic way as usual. I hate computers.

Comment: I think the answer below this one should be the real accepted answer by this time :)

Answer (score 251):

**UPDATED 20/10/2022**

If you are using **Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.x.y** you will find these folders:

- in **Windows** should be in `c:\user\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioX.Y`
- in **Linux** should be in `/home/yourname/.config/Google/AndroidStudioX.Y` and `/home/yourname/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioX.Y`
- in **Mac** should be in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.X.Y`

If you are using **AndroidStudio Arctic Fox 2020.3** you will find these folders:

- in **Windows** should be in `c:\user\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioX.Y`
- in **Linux** should be in `/home/yourname/.config/Google/AndroidStudioX.Y` and `/home/yourname/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioX.Y`
- in **Mac** should be in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioX.Y`

If you are using **AndroidStudio 4.1/4.2** you will find these folders:

- in **Windows** should be in `c:\user\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioX.Y`
- in **Linux** should be in `/home/yourname/.config/Google/AndroidStudioX.Y` and `/home/yourname/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioX.Y`
- in **Mac** should be in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioX.Y`

If you are using **AndroidStudio 2.1-4.0** you will find these folders:

- in **Windows** should be in `c:\user\yourname\.AndroidStudioX.Y`
- in **Linux** should be in `/home/yourname/.AndroidStudioX.Y`
- in **Mac** should be in `~/Library/Preferences/.AndroidStudioX.Y`

If you are using **AndroidStudio 2.0** you will find these folders:

- in **Windows** should be in `c:\user\yourname\.AndroidStudio2.0`
- in **Linux** should be in `/home/yourname/.AndroidStudio2.0`
- in **Mac** should be in `~/Library/Preferences/.AndroidStudio2.0`

If you are using **AndroidStudio 1.5** you will find these folders:

- in **Windows** should be in `c:\user\yourname\.AndroidStudio1.5`
- in **Linux** should be in `/home/yourname/.AndroidStudio1.5`
- in **Mac** should be in `~/Library/Preferences/.AndroidStudio1.5`

If you are using **.AndroidStudioPreview 1.4** you will find these folders:

- in **Windows** should be in `c:\user\yourname\.AndroidStudioPreview1.4`
- in **Linux** should be in `/home/yourname/.AndroidStudioPreview1.4`
- in **Mac** should be in `~/Library/Preferences/.AndroidStudioPreview1.4`

If you are using **AndroidStudio 1.3** you will find these folders:

- in **Windows** should be in `c:\user\yourname\.AndroidStudio1.3`
- in **Linux** should be in `/home/yourname/.AndroidStudio1.3`
- in **Mac** should be in `~/Library/Preferences/.AndroidStudio1.3`

Your setting (with a **Preview** version):

- in **Windows** should be in `c:\user\yourname\.AndroidStudioPreview`
- in **Linux** should be in `/home/yourname/.AndroidStudioPreview`
- in **Mac** should be in `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview`

Comment: I had to go back to my old version of android studio (which from previous breaking upgrades I learned to keep), and do "export settings" from there first, before I could import into the new version. Otherwise I was getting error "could not find settings.jar". It also default saved the settings to `.AndroidStudioPreview\config` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure why the IDE does not just propose the default folders you mentioned if the user does not know where they are...

Comment: On Mac, ~/Library/...  didn't work for me in 0.8.0. I had to use /Users/{USERNAME}/Library.

Comment: For me to upgrade from 1.0.8 to 1.1.0, the configuration folder on Windows 8.1 is "E:\Users\myname\.AndroidStudio\config".  I have redirected user folders from drive C to drive E.

Comment: As of Android Studio 3.0, these prefs can be found in `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.0/` on mac - I assume Linux and Windows locations have changed accordingly (`s/.AndroidStudio2.1/AndroidStudio3.0/`, note the lack of a dot prefix)

Comment: Config directory for Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9 on Linux can be found in `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1`

Answer (score 9):

Starting with [Android Studio 0.8.0](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-8-0) (Beta) its now

```
/home/{username}/.AndroidStudioBeta
```

for a *nix environment

**UPDATE:**

Since [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#top) is now out of beta the settings can now be found in:

```
/home/{username}/.AndroidStudio
```

Answer (score 9):

On mac Sierra, Android studio 2.3

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.3/
```

Answer (score 6):

On my Mac, using Android Studio 2.1, the directory is

`~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.1/`

that is, not a hidden dir.

Answer (score 5):

For Linux and Android Studio 4.2+, the location is:

`/home/[username]/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

assuming you are upgrading from version 4.1.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to [JetBrains' documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html), but according to [Configure Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#file_location), the configuration is currently under a "Google" folder:

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Google\<product><version>`
- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/<product><version>`
- Linux: `~/.config/Google/<product><version>`

That's where I found them (the Mac variant).

Answer (score 2):

And in a *nix environment, this will probably be located at `/home/[username]/.AndroidStudioPreview`

Answer (score 2):

for Android Studio 4.2, Google has moved it to `%appdata%\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.2`

Answer (score 1):

There is a single point of reference for the location of the settings folder for all Jetbrains IDE's for all OS's:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

  - [**2020.1 and above versions**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs)
  - [**2019.3.x and below versions**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs)

To migrate the settings look for the folder listed under ***Configuration directory***

Comment: The authoritative documentation for JetBrains IDEs seems like a good thing to link to, but it seems that nowadays this is no longer accurate for Android Studio. Instead see Google's documentation for Android Studio configuration, or Gabriele's answer.