# How does the Android gradle plugin select all devices?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I am writing a small gradle plugin where I need to use the adb command. My question is how does the `installDebug` task know all the devices? By default it will been installed on all devices. I found the [`installTask`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/tasks/InstallTask.groovy) but there is no `-s` argument for specifying a device.

How did they manage that in the [Android gradle plugin](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle)?

Bonus question: In Android Studio I can select a special device, how can I know that from the gradle script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InstallTask` is not present in the latest sources. The [`InstallVariantTask`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/9fba95348ef762fd9a7c82ac332d119684a74bcb/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/tasks/InstallVariantTask.groovy) is used instead of it. As you can see from its sources it checks `ANDROID_SERIAL` environment variable for specific device selection and if the variable is not present then the install task is run against all compatible devices (the same is done for [uninstall](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59894) and [connectedAndroidTest](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75407) tasks).

Bonus answer: that's not possible AFAIK. Android Studio [does not install/launch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/run/AndroidRunningState.java) the application via gradle. In `.idea/workspace.xml` file you will find the `ANDROID_EXTENDED_DEVICE_CHOOSER_SERIALS` property, which is updated at some point of time after your APK was deployed, but this info is not available during the gradle script run.

Comment: That looks like what I was searching for. Thank you! I will evaluate it and accept/upvote.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Android Studio `.idea/deploymentTargetDropDown.xml` will contain a list of possible targets, the most recently *selected* target, and the *time* at which it was selected

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="deploymentTargetDropDown">
    <runningDeviceTargetSelectedWithDropDown>
      <Target>
        <type value="RUNNING_DEVICE_TARGET" />
        <deviceKey>
          <Key>
            <type value="SERIAL_NUMBER" />
            <value value="some_serial_number" />
          </Key>
        </deviceKey>
      </Target>
    </runningDeviceTargetSelectedWithDropDown>
    <timeTargetWasSelectedWithDropDown value="2023-02-22T12:03:45.955233Z" />
 </component>
```

The same file is also stored in the [settings directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460241/3808828)

It seems like an implementation detail not to be relied on for anything mission critical, but is populated as soon as you make a selection, making it useful for deployment related scripts