# Android Studio : decrease font size

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I was adjusting the font size of android studio (gui) in its settings, but (seems like) I typed something wrong and font size have changed to 100+. Now I can't see nothing more than a one  symbol on the whole screen, and I can't navigate to settings to change it back. What I can do now? What file I have to modify since Android Studio isn't responding at all?

Comment: Hahaha, that's awesome. What OS are you on? You should be able to remove the IDE's files under your user directory. They should then be recreated with the default values. Also maybe mousewheel + ctrl works.

Comment: Delete .android-studio2.1(the version may differ in your context)  which is hidden directory in your home directory

Comment: See Gabriele Marioti's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458923/from-where-do-i-import-settings-from-previous-version-of-android-studio)

Comment: @LaxmanBhattarai thanks I've forgot about options in hidden directory .android, now that's alright!!

For those who maybe got in same trouble, change font in .androidstudio2.1/config/options/ui.lnf.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `.android-studio2.1(`the version may differ in your concerned   which is hidden directory in your home directory  it will reset your setting .

Answer (score 0):

As Android Studio is basically IntelliJ + some extra stuff, here are docs you want to check:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

and substitute `<PRODUCT>` with `AndroidStudio`. You may either wipe the whole config directory or if you got some settings tweaked already, you may try to search config files for `font` or so as these are usually plain XML files.