# May I remove the folder named ".AndroidStudio3.0" after update completed?

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I updated Android Studio from version 3.0 to 3.1.
But in USER directory, the old folder named `.Android Studio3.0` has been remained with a new folder which is `.Android Studio3.1`. May I remove older one?

this is the image that I captured my own USER directory:

[image]

Comment: you may remove if you have not imported any settings from 3.0, I have faced settings being deleted in older versions of studio, to be on the safe side delete everything older than 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the old folder after you have successfully upgrade your Android Studio. But you need to keep the folder until you're completely assure that all of your previous projects are working fine with the newest Android Studio.

You need to keep the folder in case if you want to fallback to the old Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

yes after import setting from old to new or you don't need to import,you can delete old

Answer (score 0):

Yes of-course,

As `.AndroidStudio` folder contains settings for Andriod Studio so you can delete old entry after importing your setting to new android studio.

**Things to consider:**

1. Check if all your project are running in flow in new version of android. Because it is very hard some time to upgrade project gradle with new android studio if project is using some jni etc.
2. Import your previous setting of android studio to the newer. It contains all your themes, plugins and customisation. Which you never want to configure again.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24458923/6891563) for how to import setting.