# How to move an Android emulator to another device?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

This question has been asked before, but none of the answers actually works. Seems like a lot of things has changed with emulators.

Here are two related questions:

- [Android Emulator: How to Copy an Emulator / AVD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864637/android-emulator-how-to-copy-an-emulator-avd)
- [Android - How
  to copy the emulator to a friend for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575167/android-how-to-copy-the-emulator-to-a-friend-for-testing)

But I tried both solutions. None of them seems to be working. I have got an emulator on my computer. I installed a few android apps on it and made some progress on these apps(it has user data). I want to copy the entire AVD to another Machine such that I can resume using this AVD on a new machine with all the user data preserved.

I don't know why, but copying the entire **device.avd/** folder and device.ini seems to be not working. I also copied the entire **system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/** folder as *userdata.img* is now in that folder. But still, the new emulator doesn't contain my installed apps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've just had to do this with a KitKat emulator and can confirm it worked fine for me, zipped up .ini file with it's avd folder, copied to new machine, unzipped and copied the file and folder into C:\Users\Daniel\.android\avd